# Integration of a first order function with respect to time

Tags: calculus, integration

$$x'(t) = -x(t) + exp(t)$$

Can anyone please provide guidance on how to solve for $x(t)$?

Comment: Here's one way: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor

Comment: $x(t)=\dfrac{e^t}2+\dfrac C{e^t}~$

Answer (score 1):

It is done in two steps.

1). Consider the associated homogeneous equation (you forget about the "free term", i.e. the term not containing the unknown function $x$): $ x'(t) = -x(t)$. This equation has the solution, $x(t) = \mathbb{e}^{-t} K$, with $K$ some constant.

2). Now, "vary" the constant obtained above, i.e. assume that it now becomes a function of $t$, therefore $x(t) = \mathbb{e}^{-t} K(t)$. Plug this new form of $x$ back into the original equation. This will produce another differential equation, this time the unknown function being $K$ (also note how terms containing underived $K$ magically vanish!): $K'(t) = \mathbb{e}^{2t}$. This new equation has for solution $K(t) = \frac {\mathbb{e} ^{2t}}{2} + C$, with $C$ some  other constant. Now plug this $K(t)$ back into the formula of $x(t)$ from the previous step, obtaining $\frac {\mathbb{e} ^t}{2} + \frac {C}{\mathbb{e} ^t}$.

If you also have some initial condition, using it in a third step will fix $C$.

This procedure is a classic one, known as the "variation of constants method" (because in step 1 you allow the constant $K$ to become a function $K(t)$, and thus to "vary").

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve this one. First take $x(t)$ to the left side so that:
\begin{equation}
x'(t)+x(t)=exp(t)
\end{equation}
Now multiply both sides with $exp(t)\neq 0$ and you will have:
\begin{equation}
exp(t)x'(t)+exp(t)x(t)=exp^2(t)
\end{equation}
Now observe that the left side is the product derivative as follows:
\begin{equation}
(exp(t)x(t))' =exp^2(t) \Leftrightarrow exp(t)x(t)=\frac{1}{2}exp^2(t)+c \Leftrightarrow x(t)=\frac{1}{2}exp(t)+cexp^{-1}(t)
\end{equation}
and $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Now taking into account that $x(t_0)=x_0$, for some $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ you will have:
\begin{equation}
x(t_0)=\frac{1}{2}exp(t_0)+cexp^{-1}(t_0) \Leftrightarrow c=exp(t_0)(x_0-\frac{1}{2}exp(t_0))
\end{equation}
and your final solution to the Cauchy problem above will be:
\begin{equation}
x(t)=\frac{1}{2}exp(t)+(exp(t_0)(x_0-\frac{1}{2}exp(t_0)))exp^{-1}(t)
\end{equation}